# C++ Pack RGBA to unsigned int

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

With the following class, assuming RGBA are all between 0-255

```
class Color {
    public:
        short int r;
        short int g;
        short int b;
        short int a;
```

I've seen libraries such as the aging GD library using bitshifting and &, like

```
 ((r & 0x7F000000) << 24) & ...
```

but I'm concerned this might be slow, and I'd prefer a more common approach. Anyone know how I could pack the RGBA values into an unsigned int without using excessive bitwise operators(the GD approach uses about 6-8 bitshift per byte).

Comment: Do you **really** have a solid reason to believe that the speed of bitshifting is the bottleneck in your application?

Comment: If you really fear that it costs too much time, you can still use a `union` that contains an `unsigned int` as well as an unnamed `struct` with 4 `char` fields. Note that 4 `short int` in your code snippet won't trivially fit into an `unsigned int`, though.

Comment: It's more the fact that this will be a back-end class, and if someone later decides that this class is lagging their application or the method I used is too slow, I'm gonna hear it.

Comment: Masked bitshifting is the fastest way to do this on contemporary CPUs. The only way to improve on it is to directly call the "shift with masked insert" hardware opcode on CPUs that have it, like PPC's `rlwimi` op. I optimize exactly this kind of code for a living. The caveat is that the shift factor must be an immediate constant -- if you shift by variable amount (eg `r << x` where x is an int, not an immediate) then that is much slower.   Using a union is usually *slower* because most compilers don't emit very good code for unions. (They *could* emit optimal code... but they don't.)

Comment: @Crashworks, that's very interesting. I'll have to test that some time.

Answer (score 2):

If you store the rgba values in the class in the appropriate order, just interpret the class instance as an unsigned int. No time. It's done all the time in C.

See Mark's answer for more detail.

Comment: But in this case of course `unsigned char` should be used instead of `short` (which is usually 16bit).

Comment: But for that the OP would have to change the class definition to use `unsigned char`s, non?

Comment: Oh yeah, they'd need to be unsigned chars... But this is doable, right?

Comment: What about alignment? cannot it be an issue, at least theoretically?

Comment: @Andy: yes, at least indirectly. The compiler can insert padding between members of a struct. It has to be able to access `char`s without padding, but it may insert the padding for extra performance anyway.

Comment: Yes, alignment very well could.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to redefine your `Color` class to hold `unsigned char` rather than `short`, and make sure they're in the correct order for the endianness of your processor. Then make it a union with a 32-bit integer type.

Comment: And then watch the compiler insert padding between the members, and all your code break horribly.

Comment: @Jerry Ugh, that happened to me once. It resulted in a rather angry support call to the compiler vendor and a hasty patch from them.

Comment: @Crashworks: It shouldn't have -- they were right and you were wrong.

Comment: @Jerry Practically speaking, so many games depend on packed union behavior that a compiler which inserts unnecessary padding is exhibiting a bug. In addition to breaking graphics libraries, it also wastes precious cache memory and hurts performance.

Answer (score 2):

Bit shifts of a constant amount are not slow. Masking is generally not slow.

On some processors, variable shifts are slow. But packing RGBA colors into an integer does not involve variable shifts, so it tends to be not slow.

Comment: r << 24 | g << 16 | b << 8 | a involves some shifting.  As his values are 16-bit, they should be masked as well.  If they were 8-bit and your memory was 4-byte aligned, they you could get away with no shifts.

Comment: @MSN: actually, it can be pretty slow on some fairly common processors. Older Intel CPUs had a partial register stall that you were likely to hit with this. Newer ones avoid that, but still have to insert a `sync` micro-op after you OR the pieces together. That's not nearly as slow as the PRS was, but it's still a substantial slow-down.

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise operators aren't really "slow".  Actually, they are usually some of the fastest operations a CPU can execute.  Heck ARM gives you shifts for free most of the time.  When it comes down to it, if you want to pack vars into a smaller space safely (making sure of no bit overflow), you need to use the bitwise functions.  Even bitfields internally default to them.